# iPad Mini Anomaly

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a universal iOS app which now runs faultlessly on iPhone 4/5 and iPad. However on iPad mini there is no keyboard tap sounds, (but synthesizer sounds works OK). Also there appears an underline on all button text images except one. I can find no difference in coding or Storyboard settings for the working properly button image, so can't see why this should be happening on the others.

1. Is there a problem with iPad Mini sound, (keyboard clicks).
2. What might cause graphic images which appear OK on iPhone and iPad, to be differently displayed on iPad Mini?

(Not enough reputation points to offer images, sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a problem with iPad Mini sound, (keyboard clicks).

Open the **Settings** app and go to the Sounds panel. Turn the **Keyboard clicks** switch on.

> What might cause graphic images which appear OK on iPhone and iPad, to be differently displayed on iPad Mini?

Compare the settings in Settings->General->Accessibility. I'm not sure which setting might cause this, but it sounds like the kind of thing you'd see with Accessibility.